# Favorite way to modify a voice

Tags: design, spectral, plugin

Without the spectral and timbral processing functions of Kyma, I'd like to figure out how to modify human voice.  I'd love to get the spectral and timbral properties of a wolf and cross it with a man to make a more rich, sound designed voice.
Kyma has a spectral/timbral footprint style processing function among many others.  Any plugins out there to use for spectral/timbral mushing?

Answer (score 3):

Hello,

There are a number of ways of doing this Sound Hack has a variable cross convolution process and is great ( as is FScape ). Spectrumworx Audiosculpt SPEAR Composers Desktop Project can all do this kind of thing. Alchemy and metasynth as mentioned are also very good .

I was recently at a kyma Conference and got to meet a fantastic chap called Pete Johnston (check out his work here http://www.bantusound.com/) who gave demonstration on morphing. Some of the general principles apply to any software. General things you may know already (apologies if you do) such as choosing the the point of transformation can make the transition more or less believable. It is easier to transition harmonic material and harmonic material that is similar in pitch. Therefore it is a good idea to preprocess the sound files so they have similar pitch and formant characteristics. Here is a link to the video where he explains it more clearly.

http://ssc-media.com/Movies/KISS2011/TheWireBetween.mov

I should think the wolf to voice should be a great starting point as there can be lots of harmonic material in the howl of the wolf (I think pete may have an example on his site)

This is my first post so please feel free to amend if I have inadvertently broken any codes.

Best of luck.
s

Comment: Great post! Welcome aboard :) 

Answer (score 1):

[FScape](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fscape/) is a great standalone, non-realtime audio mangler. I'm not too familiar with Kyma, but I think the convolution operation would be able to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try out some vocoder plugs? I've heard Alchemy can go some cool sample morphing type stuff too. Maybe even give a demo of Metasynth a whirl!

Comment: @Andy, I've been demoing Metasynth and it is pretty incredible but you can only cross a sound with a waveform.

Comment: I mean wavetable wave form


Answer (score 1):

My absolute, all-time, mega-mega favourite thing to do to voices is to run them through Waves' UltraPitch 6-Voices plug.  Pitching waaaay down or waaaaay up and then playing with the formant regions is probably the most fun thing in the entire wide world.

It doesn't do spectral stuff, but if you layer the messed up stuff in under the "Clean" stuff you'd be amazed how natural your weird can sound.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for Native Instrument Vokator, I never found anything better for processing voice. Such a shame this piece of software was abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

How funny just saw this, probably not entirely what you are after but...

http://news.symbolicsound.com/

@Andy Lewis . Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Ircam Trax v3](http://www.fluxhome.com/products/plug_ins/ircam_trax-v3) plugin that does sound morphing.

"TRAX Cross Synthesis v3 utilizes a phase vocoder (the amplitude and the frequency/phase spectra), to **morph the spectral characteristics of two sounds**. The amplitude and frequency/phase spectra can be blended continuously and since the features that are used here are strongly nonlinear, the sound morphing is nonlinear as well, offering a way to create a wide range of new exciting and unusual sound effects."

If someone wants to learn more scientifically about it: Marcelo Caetano from [IRCAM](http://ircam.fr) did some fine work on cross-synthesis, here is his [PhD](http://recherche.ircam.fr/anasyn/caetano/caetano_morphing_musical_instrument_sounds.pdf) on the subject, and other [publications](http://recherche.ircam.fr/anasyn/caetano/publications.html).